# c# how to code a class method that can be called on the instance of the class

Tags: c#, method-call

using c# .net 4.7.1 I have a class called `Deck`, here's the code:

```
public class Deck
{
    public Card[] DeckOfCards { get; private set; } = new Card[56];        

    public Deck()
    {
        DeckOfCards = NewDeck();
    }

    private Card[] NewDeck()
    {
        Card[] newDeck = new Card[56];
        ....
        return newDeck;
    }
}
```

I would like to declare a class method within `Deck` called `Shuffle` that I would be able to call on the instance of `Deck` that I create. Here's how I picture my Main method in my program looking like:

```
class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Deck WorkingDeck = new Deck();
        WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards.Shuffle();
        ....
    }
}
```

Here's all I have for the class method `Shuffle` so far:

```
    public Card[] Shuffle(this Card[] DeckToShuffle)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Card[] ShuffledDeck = DeckToShuffle.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        return ShuffledDeck;
    }
```

But this requires that I pass a `Card[]` in my method call. I would like the method to use `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards` as the `Deck` that gets shuffled. Can someone point me in the right direction to be able to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to expose `DeckOfCards`. You have a non-static class class `Deck`. Have it represent a deck of cards. Have a constructor that takes a flag about whether it should include jokers. Have a method called `Shuffle`, another called `TakeTopCard`. and another called `Deal` with two parameters, `cardsPerHand` and `hands`. But don't expose your deck of cards storage directly. That way if you decide that a `List<Card>` makes more sense than an array, you can change the implementation without changing the public abstraction of a deck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular scenario, an Extension method would be a good solution.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Shuffle(this IEnumerable<Card> source)
    {
        // Body of Shuffle
    }
}
```

This would help you call shuffle as you desired

```
Deck WorkingDeck = new Deck();
WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards.Shuffle();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I had a feeling that the `this` keyword was a part of the solution but this is the first I've heard about Extension methods. Accepted as answer and up voted. Thank you very much.

Comment: I might have spoke too soon. Your answer does allow me to call the `Shuffle` method like this `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards.Shuffle()` and the value of `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards` does get passed to the extension method but the value of `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards` is not changed in my main method after `Shuffle` has been called. There's something missing so that the new "ShuffledDeck" is not getting passed back to the main method. Can you assist me any further?

Comment: ok, I played around with it and figured out that in order for the value to be reflected in my main method I had to declare another `Card[]` and set that value equal to `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards.Shuffle();` so my main method has this in it now: `Card[] ShuffledDeck = WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards.Shuffle();` I think that there isn't a way to just change the value of `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards` directly so a new `Card[]` has to be declared like I have it. If anyone knows how I can change the value of `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards` directly I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can simplify your `Deck` class as follows:

```
public class Deck {

    public Card[] DeckOfCards { get; private set; } = NewDeck();

    private static Card[] NewDeck() {
        Card[] newDeck = new Card[56];
        ....
        return newDeck;
    }
}
```

If you wish to make `Shuffle` change the order of cards in your `Deck`, you could write an extension method, like this:

```
static class DeckExtensions {

    public static void Shuffle(this deck)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        deck.DeckOfCards = deck.DeckOfCards.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
    }

}
```

Comment: can be an instance method of `Deck` like andrew suggested

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Absolutely. In the title of the question the author is asking for a class method, though.

Comment: "A class method that can be called on an instance of a class"...  Come to think of it, maybe that's an apt description of an extension method :-)

Comment: @dasbinkenlight , thanks a lot for the advice and the answer. Already accepted first answer as accepted answer but up voted this as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd My favorite description of this kind has always been "An ellipse is a circle inscribed in a square with unequal sides" :-)

Comment: If you are implementing the class, why an extension method? You can just use a method method.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight for your suggestion to work to simplify my code the `NewDeck` method has to have the `static` keyword added to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `DeckOfCards` property is a member of the class. A method on a class can automatically access its members (either implicitly or via the `this` keyword).

```
public class Deck
{
    public Card[] DeckOfCards { get; private set; };        

    public Deck()
    {
        this.DeckOfCards = NewDeck();
    }

    static Card[] NewDeck()
    {
        Card[] newDeck = new Card[56];
        ....
        return newDeck;
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Card[] shuffledDeck = this.DeckOfCards.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
        this.DeckOfCards = shuffledDeck;
    }
}
```

You would invoke it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Deck workingDeck = new Deck();
    workingDeck.Shuffle();
    ....
}
```

This design has `Deck` as a mutable object: `Shuffle` alters the order of the existing deck, rather than creates a different deck.

As an aside, there are better shuffling methods to use. The term to Google here is 'Fisher-Yates algorithm'.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. First thing the `Shuffle` method returns a `Card[]` but the method definition says it returns `void`. Fixing that I still can't call the `Shuffle` method like this `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards.Shuffle()`. Writing an extension class as described in the two other answers worked for my situation. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @I_am_Jacks_colon I've added an extra part on how it would be called in this instance.. I agree that the extension method approach feels more elegant.

Comment: I actually like this better. I think that it's cleaner to have the method within the `Deck` class definition and I LOVE that I can just call `WorkingDeck.Shuffle()` and it changes `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards` without having to declare a new `Card[]` and assign it to the shuffled value of `WorkingDeck.DeckOfCards`. I don't want to take the accepted answer away from Anu Viswan, but this deserves an up vote for sure. This really is exactly what I wanted. THANKS for the answer!!!! Note: the `Shuffle()` method still needs to be changed to return a `Card[]` instead of `void`  ;)

Comment: @I_am_Jacks_colon: I could change the signature to return a `Card[]`, or I could change the method implementation so it doesn't return anything. I've changed the method implementation, I feel that it keeps with the encapsulated design approach.

Comment: great points, I completely agree. I think that changing the signature of `Shuffle()` to return `void` and then changing the definition of the method so it doesn't return a `Card[]` looks great.